# Cloning a git repo with "Secret text" credential as password

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a token stored in "Secret text" credential, and am trying to use that token as a password while cloning a git repo.

I do not want to use "Username with password" credential, as only the token is needed and I do not want to create a duplicate credential with a dummy username.

This works:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    TOKEN = credentials('git-token')
    REPO = "https://_:$TOKEN@gitea.example.org/org/repo"
  }
  stages {
    stage("Clone") {
      steps {
        git env.REPO
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But triggers a warning:

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "withEnv" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [TOKEN]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
```

Trying to use shell environment variables (replacing `"` with `'` in the declaration or `REPO`) fails:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://_:%24TOKEN@gitea.example.org/org/repo +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Not found.
```

What are my options, besides creating a dummy credential?

Answer (score 0):

For now I have created a "Username + password" credential with a dummy username instead of the "Secret text" one, and am using a following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    CREDS_ID = 'git-token'
    REPO = "https://gitea.example.org/org/repo"

    // Instead of "$TOKEN", use "$CREDS_PSW" in the script.
    // `credentials(CREDS_ID)` does not work, as `credentials`
    // requires a string as an argument.
    CREDS = credentials("${env.CREDS_ID}")
  }
  stages {
    stage("Clone") {
      steps {
        git url: env.REPO, credentialsId: CREDS_ID
      }
    }
  }
}
```